# update-alternatives: error: alternative path ... doesn't exist

Tags: apt

```
$ apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop
...
Setting up oxygen-cursor-theme (0.0.2012-06-kde4.8-2.1ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/X11/cursors/oxy-white.theme doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package oxygen-cursor-theme (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oxygen-cursor-theme
 kde-workspace-data
 kde-workspace-bin
 kde-workspace
 kde-plasma-desktop
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixed it:

```
dpkg --purge oxygen-cursor-theme
apt-get clean
apt-get -f install
```